Using condformat package to format dataframe
I'm trying to conditionally colour three columns in my df using the condformat package. I have succeeded with one (Percentage), but can't understand why the others (AnswerA and AnswerB) aren't working. I'd really appreciate any guidance.
Here's my code:
library(condformat)

my_df <- data.frame(
  Percentage = runif(10),
  AnswerA = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E"),
  AnswerB = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E")
)

my.df.cf <- condformat(my_df) %>%
  ## Highlight Percentages below 20% or above 80%
  rule_fill_discrete('Percentage',
                     expression = cut(Percentage, breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1), include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE),
                     colours = c('1' = 'firebrick1', '2' = 'white', '3' = 'lightgreen')) %>%
  ## Highlight when answers A and B don't match
  rule_fill_discrete(c('AnswerA','AnswerB'),
                     expression = AnswerA != AnswerB ,
                     colours = c('TRUE' = 'firebrick1', 'FALSE' = 'white')) 


Hey @VikkiO, tell us about the expected output.

I am going to export the coloured table to a MS Excel file, using condformat2excel(my.df.cf,"Question Inforation.xlsx")

Your code is working, except for color firebrick1.
Try with hex code instead:
condformat(my_df) %>%
  ## Highlight Percentages below 20% or above 80%
  rule_fill_discrete(
    columns = Percentage,
    expression = cut(
      Percentage, 
      breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1), 
      include.lowest = TRUE, 
      labels = FALSE),
    
    colours = c(
      '1' = '#FF3030', 
      '2' = '#FFFFFF', 
      '3' = '#90EE90')) %>%
  
  ## Highlight when answers A and B don't match
  rule_fill_discrete(
    columns = contains("Answer"),
    expression = AnswerA != AnswerB,
    colours = c(
      'TRUE' = '#FF3030', 
      'FALSE' = '#FFFFFF')) 

The output:


Thanks a million Adriano, you're a legend! The issue was really driving me crazy!
